# To generate pass/fail automation reports in Appium using Android studio with Testng or with any other tool

Tags: testng, report, appium

I want to generate the reports in mobile automation using appium with the help of Testng or any other tool in which I can have test cases such as pass/fail

And also please suggest the libraries or jar files required for that tool

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `Extent Report` is good option with Testng. It's very expressive and represent more details about your test execution. You can check how to implement it in below link and some report sample also.

https://www.swtestacademy.com/extentreports-testng/

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

For Automation testing and Reporting you have to first check what you need as report.

1. Go for a BDD framework, like Cucumber + Gherkin
2. Check Maven project setup for Java, easy way to maintain .jar files as dependencies
3. Integrate your reporting for the framework
4. Execute the test Junit and get the execution status as report. the report will present you the pass fail status of each BDD step that you write.

A video guide to setup and execute

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSMFeUcRuAqIGQu3RWOlCRg

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of the [TestNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#reporters--loggers). One of the very well-known is [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf), providing TestNG implementation for web, mobile and web-services with [detailed reporting](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/dashboard.htm) including screenshots and command log. You can author test in JAVA or BDD using different features required for test automation.

Here you can find [step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try in Appium Studio. It comes up bundled with all the required libraries and a built in reporting mechanism and cloud devices.
You can have a look at their [documentation](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Appium+Studio).